# altering form with hook_form_FORM_ID_Alter

Tags: forms

```
function dental_form_simplenews_block_form_2_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
    global $user;
    $form = array();
    $form['#attributes'] = array('class' => array('newsletter'));
    /*$form['subscribe'] = array(
        '#type' => 'fieldset', 
        '#title' => '', 
        '#weight' => 5, 
        '#collapsible' => TRUE
    );*/
    if ($user->uid) {

    }
    else {
        $form['mail'] = array(
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#title' => t('Email'),
            '#size' => 20,
            '#maxlength' => 128,
            '#required' => TRUE,
            '#attributes' => array('class' => array('text_ip')),
        );
        $submit_text = t('Subscribe');
        $form['action'] = array(
          '#type' => 'value',
          '#value' => 'subscribe',
          '#attributes' => array('class' => 'submit'),
        );
    }

    return $form;

}
```

Above is the code i am using to alter form produced by simplenews plugin. But i am getting various error messages.

```
Notice: Undefined index: #parents in form_builder() (line 1713 of /home/sjd/www/example.com/includes/form.inc).
Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in form_builder() (line 1713 of /home/sjd/www/example.com/includes/form.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: #tree in form_builder() (line 1743 of /home/sjd/www/example.com/includes/form.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: #array_parents in form_builder() (line 1766 of /home/sjd/www/example.com/includes/form.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: process_input in _form_builder_handle_input_element() (line 1904 of /home/sjd/www/example.com/includes/form.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: complete form in form_builder() (line 1723 of /home/sjd/www/example.com/includes/form.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: #tree in form_builder() (line 1743 of /home/sjd/www/example.com/includes/form.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: #array_parents in form_builder() (line 1766 of /home/sjd/www/example.com/includes/form.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: process_input in _form_builder_handle_input_element() (line 1904 of /home/sjd/www/example.com/includes/form.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: process_input in drupal_process_form() (line 817 of /home/sjd/www/example.com/includes/form.inc).
```

Can anybody tell me where i am going wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't reset the form completely by doing `$form = array();`, since you will delete some of the stuff Drupal expects to be there.

You should instead do something like this:

```
function dental_form_simplenews_block_form_2_alter(&$form, &$form_state)
{
    global $user;
    // Remove what you don't want..
    unset($form['fields']);
    // Add what you do want..
    $form['#attributes'] = array('class' => array('newsletter'));
   ...
}
```

Comment: You actually shouldn't use unset at all. Instead, set #access to false. `$form['fields']['#access'] = FALSE;`. Or as Dave Reid put it: http://twitter.com/#!/davereid/status/76792614602547202

Comment: How do i remove the labels from the form?

Comment: @Berdir I've actually seen cases where setting access to false would cause error but using unset would work fine. For the most part, however, using access is the best option.