# How to remove link of username in comment submission form

Tags: comments

How can I remove the username link which is displayed in the comment submission form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Simple solution is to use CSS. Just add a css rule to your theme's stylesheet.

   ```
   #some .rule {display: none;}
   ```
2. Alternatively you can use `hook_form_alter` to modify the form and remove the link or change it to something else.

   How to do it depends on your Drupal verion, see the [API docs](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) for reference or see [altering form with hook_form_FORM_ID_Alter](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5727/altering-form-with-hook-form-form-id-alter/5730#5730) for usage on `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter` which is a specialized version of `hook_form_alter`.

Comment: as i am newbie could you please explain how to resolve it... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Edit the content type (in Drupal 7 this is under Structure -> Content types), and choose "Anonymous posters may not enter their contact information".

Comment: Thanks for the reply dylan... But i need to remove the link which leads to profile page when we click on the name of the registered user in comment submission form...

Comment: Do you want to remove the name entirely, or change it to plain text?  What version of Drupal are you using?

Comment: I need to change it in to plain text... D6 i am using

Answer (score 0):

I would try doing this in the comments.css stylesheet. That was the easiest way for me. 
In the Zen theme the style was in comments.css

```
.comment .submitted /* The "posted by" information */ a {
        pointer-events: none;
       cursor: default;
       text-decoration:none;
       color:#000;
}
```